# Can't get HTTP 201 response

Tags: javascript, html, http

I am trying to get HTTP 201 response from this code but I can't get. Please help me in solving the problems related to this code.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <center>
    <h2>PAY</h2>

    <div id="demo">
    <button type="button" onclick="lol()">payhere</button>
    </div>

    <script>
   function lol() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 | this.status == 201) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alert(this.responseText);
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.test.com/cors", true);
    xhttp.withCredentials = true;
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify('{"returnUrl":"x","cancelUrl":"x","offerCredit":false,"experienceProfile":{"brandName":"test.com","noShipping":"true","addressOverride":false},"testLibraryVersion":"test/web/3.31.0","_meta":{}'));
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Http status in the form 2xx are really not something to be wished at client side. It is a response code that is sent by server depending on how it&amp;#39;s coded there. 201 mainly means created but I can return 200 instead saying a Ok meaning whatever the code was supposed to do has been done.

Comment: You can't assign `statusCode` outside `onreadystatechange` before request has been made or completed

Comment: @AvinashSagar When I tried this request with burpsuite I got an HTTP 201 response but when try to get this response through this code I can't get 201 response. I am also getting 200 response but it is giving me an error page. In response.

Comment: Ok. So it means you are getting a response with status 200 and some content along with it. 201 is returned normally without content. I would ask you to confirm the same request headers in burpsuite and your code. I think, adding an accept header with right media type will help.

Comment: @AvinashSagar Request - `POST /merchants HTTP/1.1 
Host: api.main.com 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0 
Accept: */* 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Referer: https://www.test.com/upgrade?selectPlan= 
Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 603 
Origin: https://test2.com
Connection: close` 

`{"returnUrl":"x","cancelUrl":"x","offerCredit":false,"experienceProfile":{"brandName":"test.com","noShipping":"true","addressOverride":false},"testLibraryVersion":"test/web/3.31.0","_meta":{}}`

Comment: @AvinashSagar The code is the same which I have used above.

Comment: @Dhananjay - Please add accept header in your code like below:     xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: @AvinashSagar Thank you very much my almost problem is solved. I have one small question the data which I am sending to the website which is in the xhttp.send() is that a correct way to send data. I have replaced JSON.stringify()  with JSON.parser() but it is throwing me an error. I think the error is there because of the way I am sending this request. 
And I have also changed "GET" request with "POST" request.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dhananjay - xhttp.send() is the correct way since you are using vanilla javascript here. I am not sure on this one but you don't need to add JSON.stringify or JSON.parser at all in the send method as the send method takes the body argument which is already a JSON in your case. Also, I will change my comment to a Answer. Please mark it so it can also help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http status in the form 2xx are really not something to be wished at client side. It is a response code that is sent by server depending on how it&#39;s coded there. 201 mainly means created but I can return 200 instead saying a Ok meaning whatever the code was supposed to do has been done. The error normally occurrs when there are missing headers or the content you sent is not correct. Please add accept header in your code like below:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!